# fb timeline no recent activity showing on website

Tags: facebook-timeline

I'm designing a website for someone and they want their fb page timeline to show on the website.

I have the fb page url https://www.facebook.com/NorfolkTankMuseum?fref=ts 
and the app-id  494199010641098
but after filling in all the info on the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity
page and enter all the code onto the webpage it just says 'no activity feed'

his old site he was using wordpress and it worked fine so his page/posts aren't hidden as it's a public page.

the code i got off fb is 
this is just inside the body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=494199010641098"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and then this goes where i want the timeline to appear.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NorfolkTankMuseum?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

what am i doing wrong pls?
i have been messing about with this for a week now with no joy

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I have sorted it sort of but couldn't get the timeline feature to work at all.     what i had to do was use the 'like box' and then click the 'add posts' checkbox. that was the only way it would work.

Comment: i see. anyways,i'll ask again. were you able to see any errors in your console when you were trying to get the timeline feature to work?